# What Effects exist and what does each Effect do?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Many of the skills indicate that they cause an **Effect** on the target stack.  For example, *Storm Winds II* states that creatures are "inflicted by the "Dazed" effect" and *Ice Armor* "applies the "Chilled" effect to attackers".

Is there a full list of these **Effects** and the effect (hah!) they have in the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the awesome fan manual linked [here](http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/5861060878/m/5131057409)

**Chilled** 
-1 Movement reduction and +20% vulnerability to damage (Fire). Lasts for 1 turn.

**Dazed** Initiative is decreased by 10. Lasts for 2 turns.

**Frozen** Movement is reduced to zero and suffers from +20% vulnerability to damage (Fire). Lasts for 1 turn.

**Soaked** 20% vulnerability to damage (Air). Lasts for 2 turns.

**Summoned** Initiative of summoned stacks is decreased by 15 for the turn they enter the combat map. They cannot be resurrected and also leave the Hero’s army after the combat.

Comment: Duration varies between the units/heroes that cast the spell.

Comment: @John Does it?  Can you give an example of something that has a different duration than the ones listed above?

Comment: I remember having played as Sanctuary once and having circle of winter chill for 2 turns

Comment: @John There is a hero skill that makes it last an extra turn, maybe that is what you saw.

Comment: Oh. Found it, eternal winter. So you mean to say that unless modified these are all standard for all creatures and spells?

Comment: @John I believe so.  I don't even think the abilities mention a duration, they just say the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

- Dazed is -10% initiative.
- Chilled is -1 movement (before talents).
- Frozen is +20% fire damage and immobilized (speed reduced to 0).
- Soaked is +20% air damage.

I'm not sure there's an out-of-game listing, anywhere, but when you're in the middle of combat, you can view all effects (and the effects of those effects) by right-clicking an affected stack, and then right-clicking the effect in question.